# JS Function inside a click for a button is being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have the following piece of code that is giving me weird behaviour

```
$("#cont_btn").click(function () {
    $("#cont_btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    selRowIds = $("#CodeGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    rowsToJson(selRowIds);
    //return false;
});
```

The button cont_btn is a button on a bootstrap 2 modal. It contains a continue button and a close button.

If I select the close button or click outside the modal to dismiss it, and then re-open the modal the function will get called twice.

I have tried using

```
.one('click', function() { ... }
```

and I have put break points on the line of
`$("#cont_btn").click(...`

click is not getting called twice. During my debugging I'm finding that the script re enters on the line of

```
 $("#cont_btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

On the page load I see that the line of

```
$("#cont_btn").click(function () {
```

Is hit but the code does not enter the function it will skip to the close button. I presume this is the listener for both buttons being initialized ?

Googling this has suggested checking that the Script isn't called twice and using return false, but nothing has worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You made a boo-boo, the event handler is inside the function that opens the modal, so everytime the modal is opened, the event handler is bound once more.

Comment: @adeneo i was about to write the same.

Comment: thanks I'll fix that now and report back

Comment: Started writing an answer and then saw adeneo's comment it is very likely to be your problem.  @adeneo, I would put that as the answer so it can be accepted and voted up.

Comment: @akousmata - how do I do that ?

Comment: ye that was the solution @adeneo if you add the answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @adeneo there should be an answer box below the comments section, once you post your answer I can accept it.

Comment: There we go, now I get it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler is inside the function that opens the modal, so everytime the modal is opened, the event handler is bound once more.